# Is there way to Pre-Fill name from the signed in Google Account in Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-api

I need to pull the name off of the GSuite Business account name and have it automatically be filled in the form when opened along with the email address. Is this possible using Apps Script?

Comment: So, if I am not mistaken you are trying to create a Google Form with a question where you will be including the full list of users in your Google Workspace account so that they can pick any name/email from the list, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use Directory API to retrieve informations about directory users.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users